# Simulate UITextField touch by UIButton

Tags: xcode, events, uibutton, uitextfield, simulate

Is there anyway to fire the "touch on UITextField" event? Because I would like to place a button that, if pressed, sets the focus on a specific UITextField and starts editing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` when user pressed on the button you want.